# Windows 7 explorer icon handler for audio files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons

I'm looking for a way to preview all of my .WAV files fast.
I don't need to hear them but prefer to "see" them, i.e. observe a plot of their wave-form (these are very short files so it is an informative view).
The best way would be if their icons will show their waveform.
I understand that it can be done through shell extension of icon handlers. Does anybody know if there is already some plug-in ready out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old, but for any future readers this functionality is available using [Tsugi QuickAudio](http://www.tsugi-studio.com/?page_id=28).

The program is paid, although there is also a free trial. Although there are several features, the one that is relevant is the following: it replaces the default previews for the audio files with their graphic representation. The representation is also customizable.

[image: folder]

Answer (score 1):

To add to this, there is also a Windows Explorer alternative called [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/) that can display .WAV thumbnail images.

Note: The software is commercial.

[image: Animated screenshot]

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Comment: @DragonLord - I originally made this post under the impression I would be able to attach the animated GIF I linked to as an inline image (in the same manner "Wayne Taylor" did) - but wasn't able to because posting inline images requires more reputation than I currently have. Feel free to remove the post if you like.

Comment: Edited the image into the post.

Answer (score 0):

I *highly* doubt such an extension already exists. One possible alternative could be an app like [**ThumbsPlus**](http://www.cerious.com):

> ThumbsPlus is a highly customizable image database with thumbnails and batch editing. It makes it easy to catalog, organize, locate and maintain all of your graphics, multimedia and font files. It runs on Windows XP, 2003, 2008, Vista and Windows 7 and 8. Both 32 and 64-bit operating systems versions are supported.

[image: 1]

Apparently it has just the [feature](http://www.cerious.com/help8sp1/type_wav.html) you seek:

> The thumbnail generated for WAV files is simply the icon of the application associated with them in Windows Explorer. To generate thumbnails from rendered audio data, see: **Options | File Loading - Movie / Sound, Render audio waveforms** option.
>
> **Render audio waveforms:** Select this option to have ThumbsPlus render audio data using the selected style. Available styles are Wave, Radial, Diagram, Tunnel , and Frequency.